# How do i use GuildChannel.Delete, with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

so, im coding my first discord bot, and i want it to do something similar to the bot [Xenon](https://top.gg/bot/xenon) where it deletes all the channels it can, but i have no idea how to do so. this is what i have so far

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "delete channels":
        await GuildChannel.Delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Guild channel from the message object
ie:

```
channel = message.channel  # The channel the message was sent
await channel.delete()
```

so with your code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "delete channels":
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.delete()
```

Comment: Any way to delete a group of channels, or all of them?

Comment: Just iterate through the channels and delete them with the .delete() method